# How to implement exit dialog everywhere (e.g after pressing back button in android) in the flutter app, that there is no path in the stack

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-go-router

I'm using go_router, if it helps!

I wanted to try go_router parameter in material.router constructor but I don't know how to do it.

Also I don't want to use onPopScope for each single of pages.

If anyone has any idea to solve this issue it's quite a big help.

Comment: so you want when the user is on the initial page and pressed the back button, to popup a dialog and when on differen page to just go to page before in stack?

Comment: nearly! I'm creating a somehow mafia game that almost everywhere in app there is no route in stck except current location, because I used go method to navigate for most routings.

Comment: you can check out `WillPopScope` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html for never versions of flutter use `PopScope` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.